# Mysql 4 to 5 query conversion - join headaches

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.5, mysql4

If anyone can help me rewrite my query to work in mysql 5 I would be very grateful. If anyone can provide links to solid, simple tutorials on how to rewrite old queries that would also be great.

My current (version 4) query looks like this:

```
SELECT
 course.course_code,
 course.course_title_sv AS course_title,
 course.course_u_credits,
 course.course_successive_level_scb_id,
 s.successive_level_scb_order,
 s.successive_level_scb_code,
 LEFT (education_level.edu_level_name_sv, 1) AS course_edu_level, course.course_level, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.head_area_hv_title_sv SEPARATOR ', ') AS head_area_hv
FROM
 course, course_event, course_event_package_links, package, education_level
LEFT JOIN
 course_has_head_area_hv ON(course.course_id = course_has_head_area_hv.course_id)
LEFT JOIN
 head_area_hv h ON(h.head_area_hv_id = course_has_head_area_hv.head_area_hv_id)
LEFT JOIN
 successive_level_scb s ON(s.successive_level_scb_id = course.course_successive_level_scb_id)
WHERE
 course.course_edu_level=education_level.edu_level_id AND
 course.course_id=course_event.course_id AND
 course_event.course_event_id=course_event_package_links.course_event_id AND
 course_event_package_links.package_id=package.package_id AND
 course.course_successive_level_scb_id != '' AND
 package.package_id='6318'
GROUP BY course.course_id
```

Comment: And how does your error message look like?

Comment: Can you add some create statements, so we can test this ourselfs?

Comment: Join headaches, hm, I see. May it be from mixing joining in ANSI-SQL standard ON syntax and joining in WHERE clause? Avoid that!

Comment: Yeah, it's from mixing joining but I don't see how the "correct" syntax would look like. Feels like I've tried everything :) The error message is the expected "SQL Error 1054: Unknown column 'course.course_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace

```
SELECT ... 
FROM course, course_event, course_event_package_links
...
WHERE course.course_id=course_event.course_id 
AND course_event.course_event_id=course_event_package_links.course_event_id
```

by

```
SELECT ...
FROM course
JOIN course_event ON course_event.course_id = course.course_id
JOIN course_event_package_links 
  ON course_event_package_links.course_event_id = course_event.course_event_id
...
```

About your error message, are you sure `course.course_id` exists? Maybe it was replaced by `course.course_code`?

Comment: Close but I got i working based on your suggestion! Thank you very much!